# Unexpected token bug in Iron Router hooks js

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm pretty new to Meteor and am getting this error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
lib/packages/iron-router/examples/hooks/hooks.js:30:58: Unexpected token ;

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

It cropped up with the addition of [Iron-Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) to my app. The error refers to [this file](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/examples/hooks/hooks.js), specifically the line that begins `ready: promiseToReady`:

```
  this.route('adminPage', {
    path: '/admin',

    // 10. 3rd party API calls that are similar to waitOns:
    waitOn: function() {
      return {
        // this is made up but I do have code conceptually similar to this
        ready: promiseToReady(GoogleApi.call('/foo/bar'));
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think the function return is waiting for a function call, but instead it gets an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript you terminate object params with `,`, not with `;`.

Incorrect:

```
  return {
    ready: promiseToReady(GoogleApi.call('/foo/bar'));
  };
```

Correct:

```
  return {
    ready: promiseToReady(GoogleApi.call('/foo/bar')),
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into the same problem. Just remove iron-router using mrt/meteor remove iron-router and remove all the directories related to iron-router from packages folder.

Check the directory path from where you are running the mrt/meteor add command...Make sure that you run the command from your project root directory. Running it from project root directory fixed my issue..Earlier I ran the command from one of the sub folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the package had installed incorrectly. I made sure to fully delete it and reinstall:

```
> mrt remove iron-router
> meteor remove iron-router
> mrt add iron-router
> meteor add iron-router
```